# Tool for CSS extraction (and scope adjustment)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a webpage with a main parent div tag

```
<div class="mainDiv">...</div>
```

that contains a very large number of child elements. The page has an external stylesheet with mostly element selectors instead of class selectors:
Eg.

```
img {...}
```

instead of

```
.myImgCls {...}
```

I need a stylesheet that contains the global (page) css applied only to my mainDiv div tag, so that I can easily inject my mainDiv html on any page, along with that new stylesheet, **without interfering with the new page's element selectors**.

So, am basically looking for a tool that will generate something like:

```
.mainDiv img {...}
```

for everything inside my mainDiv.

Doing this manually is out of the question, because of the large number of elements in mainDiv.

To further elaborate: need this for jplist, which comes with a standard jplist.demo-pages.css; however instead of styling only the jplist instance, that standard jplist.demo-pages.css contains mostly element selectors so if I want to directly add a standard jplist instance on a page, I'd have to use jplist.demo-pages.css and that would interfere with my page's original stylesheet.

Comment: You may want to have a look into [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) for the scope adjustment part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for an easy way to nest all those elements within the main div, you could try [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/):

```
.mainDiv

    // Child selectors go here
```

Note: Indentation is important.